Calculating the asymptotic distribution of a function of an LLN-like quantity.
I'm preparing for my statistics exam. I'm considering the following question - there is a continuously differentiable strictly monotonic function $\mu : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and a function $h$. The statistical model is $\{ f( \cdot \mid \theta) \mid \theta \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and the data $X_i$ comes from this model. We assume that $\mathbb{E}_\theta(h(X)) = \mu(\theta)$ and that $\mathbb{E}_\theta(h(X)^2) < \infty$. Assume the true parameter is $\theta_0$.
The first thing I want to do is to show that $$\hat{\mu}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i)$$ can be used to define a consistent estimator for $\theta_0$.
Indeed $\hat{\mu}_n \overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} \mu(\theta_0)$ by the strong law of large numbers so by continuous mapping theorem $\mu^{-1}(\hat{\mu}_n) \overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} \theta_0$  so $\mu^{-1}(\hat{\mu}_n)$ is an appropriate estimator (is that correct?).
Now I want to compute the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\mu^{-1}(\hat{\mu}_n) - \theta_0)$. Proceeding by the delta method, we can first calculate $$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\mu}_n - \mu(\theta_0) \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} N(0, \sigma^2) = Z$$ by the central limit theorem where the variance $\sigma^2$ is appropriately defined as $\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}((h(X))^2) - \mu(\theta_0)^2$. .  Therefore by the delta method the asymptotic distribution is $$\sqrt{n}(\mu^{-1}(\hat{\mu}_n) - \theta_0) \overset{d}{\longrightarrow} -\frac{\mu'(\theta_0)}{\mu(\theta_0)^2} Z.$$
Is this estimator and asymptotic distribution correct?
